# What's preventing my footer from moving down the page?

Tags: html, css

For some reason my footer isn't moving along to the bottom of the content as it always has and I've been over my code back and forth and can't figure out the problem.  I used both html and css validators and they saw no errors in my coding.  I figured maybe I'm missing a quote or semi colon somewhere but I can't figure out what's causing the problem.

Here's a fiddle to show what's going on https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/n6xmhL2j/1/

here's the HTML

```
<body>
<div id="front_page" class="page">
    <header>WELCOME SLIDESHOW</header>

    <div id="intro_links">
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">New Artists</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">New Designs</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">New Garments</a>
        <a class="nav_link" href="#">How it Works</a>
    </div>

    <div id="new_artists" class="title_01">New Artists</div>

    <div class="new_artist_pane">
        <div class="art_pane01">

        </div>

        <div class="art_pane01">

        </div>

        <div class="art_pane01">

        </div>
    </div>

 </div><!--front_page-->

<footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

Here's the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:auto;
width:100%;
display:block;
/*background-color:#36F;*/
}

header{
width:100%;
height:444px;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}

footer{
width:100%;
height:111px;
margin-top:4%;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
}

.page{
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin-bottom:4%;
display:block;
}

#intro_links{
width:88%;
overflow:auto;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}

.nav_link{
width:23%;
height:137px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
margin:4% 0 4% 2%;
display:block;
background-color:#03C;
color:#fff;
}

.title_01{
width:44%;
height:44px;
background-color:#666;
font-size:29pt;
color:#fff;
display:block;
float:left;
clear:both;
}

.new_artist_pane{
width:66%;
height:auto;
border:solid 1px #333;
float:left;
margin:4% 0 0 2%;
display:block;
}

.art_pane01{
width:100%;
height:333px;
float:left;
border:solid 1px #CCC;
margin-bottom:4%;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such cases happen when you have elements with `float`

> Content flows down the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a right-floated box … **Since a float is not in the flow**, non-positioned block boxes created before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float didn’t exist.

add this right before closing the `div` :

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div><!--front_page-->

<footer>footer</footer>
```

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/amr4h4wc/)

Another- *and better since we don't have to add extra markup to the page* - way to do it is to add `.clearFix` class to the parent container `div` which its closing tag `</div>` is right before the `footer`, to do so change this:

```
<div id="front_page" class="page clearfix">
```

to this:

```
<div id="front_page" class="page clearfix">
```

and put this in your css:

```
.clearfix:after {
content:".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

or `:before` and `:after`:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Here's a [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/7tLbfhde/) showing the above technique

more details:
https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/n6xmhL2j/2/)**

Probably you've given `float:left` to every possible element and that's what disturbing it. Just add it to `footer` too as below:

```
footer{
    width:100%;
    height:111px;
    margin-top:4%;
    background-color:#999;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    float:left;//here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 ways to do that.

FIRST.

add `float:left;` to the footer.

```
footer{
width:100%;
height:111px;
margin-top:4%;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
float:left; // add this
}
```

SECOND.

set display of the footer `inline:block` or `inline-table`

```
footer{
width:100%;
height:111px;
margin-top:4%;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block; // or display:inline-table;
}
```

THIRD.

add `clear:both;` to the footer.

```
footer{
width:100%;
height:111px;
margin-top:4%;
background-color:#999;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
display:block;
clear:both; // add this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way and most succinct way to answer what you need is to just add the clear: both to the CSS.

```
    footer{
       width:100%;
       height:111px;
       margin-top:4%;
       background-color:#999;
       color:#fff;
       text-align:center;
       display:block;
       clear: both; //add this here
    }
```